# x86 Assembly End of Linked List

Tags: assembly, linked-list, x86, nasm

Let's assume I have a linked list, where each node holds an integer. I am able to traverse the linked list and get the value of each node; however, I'm not sure how to detect that I have reached end of the linked list. I know that the last node holds a `null`, so I tried `cmp [ebx+ecx*4],0` where basically ebx is the stack pointer to the first parameter of the function and ecx is an increment of 1 for each node. The problem is that a node in the linked list can also hold  a value of 0. How are 0 and `null` distinguished?

UPDATE:

So I tried something like this, but it ends up being an endless loop.

```
List:
    add eax, [ebx] //add the value at the address of ebx to eax
    lea ebx, [ebx+4] //update the address of ebx to the next field
    cmp ebx, 0 //check if this address is null
    jne List //if so, then stop
```

Is it correct that if I were to use `mov ebx, [ebx+4]` instead, it would be incorrect because ebx is now holding the value of the second element and not the address?

Comment: A linked list node has to have *two* fields, one for the value and one for the "next" pointer. A value of zero is indicated by the value field being zero. The end of the list is indicated by the next pointer being zero.

Comment: The data structure you're describing is *not* a linked list. In a *linked list* each item has data and one other key element: a link to the next item. That link would be NULL or 0 for the last element of the list, traditionally.

Answer (score 2):

That should be a mov, not an lea:

```
        mov     ebx,[ebx+4]
```

example code using masm structures. There's a h2inc.exe program that converts .h files to masm .inc files. It was included with masm and ml from microsoft, but stopped being included after Visual Studio 2003. You should be able to find a copy of h2inc if interested.

```
        .model FLAT
node    struct
value   dd      ?
next    dd      ?
node    ends

        .data
list0   node    {1, list1}
list1   node    {2, list2}
list2   node    {3, list3}
list3   node    {4, 0}

        .code
_main   proc    near
;       ...
        push    ebx
        xor     eax,eax
        lea     ebx,list0
        jmp     for1   ;jmp used to start off with null ptr check
for0:   add     eax,node.value[ebx]
        mov     ebx,node.next[ebx]
for1:   or      ebx,ebx
        jnz     for0
        pop     ebx
;       ...
```

Answer (score 1):

1) ListNode contains a value field and a link field (pointer), these are **different** fields.
In order to test if the element is the last one, you should check **link** variable.

```
struct ListNode {
   int val;
   ListNode* pNext;  // link to the next element
};
//...
if (pNext == nullptr) { // found last element
```

If you wrote in the assembly, the same - just check if the value of pNext field
is 0. In assembly you have no types so you cannot distinguish 0 for int and 0 for
null pointer. 
If the access to the next node is not through the link field, it is really not linked list.

2) In a language with type system, such as C++98/03, 'null pointer' and 0 were exactly the same, but C++11 introduced [nullptr](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#nullptr) value, which has a type `std::nullptr_t`, different from an integral type.

Comment: How do I check the link variable? Do I check the address?

Comment: Check the value of link variable that holds the address of next node.